# gcc misses a "hidden overloaded virtual function" warning

Tags: gcc, clang, constants, virtual-functions

I accidentally removed a `const` qualifier from a derived class implementation of a virtual method. I usually use clang which issues a warning about that. When I switched to gcc with `Wall` the thing goes completely unnoticed. Why is that? Here is my file:

```
$ cat main.cpp
#include <iostream>

class Father {
public:
    virtual int get() const { return 8; }
};

class Son : public Father {
public:
    virtual int get() /* const */ { return 6; }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Father *f = new Son;
    std::cout << f->get() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And here are the compilation outputs for gcc and clang:

```
$ clang++ -Wall main.cpp -o main
main.cpp:10:14: warning: 'Son::get' hides overloaded virtual function
      [-Woverloaded-virtual]
        virtual int get() /* const */ { return 6; }
                    ^
main.cpp:5:14: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'Father::get' declared
      here: different qualifiers ('const' vs unqualified)
        virtual int get() const { return 8; }
                    ^
1 warning generated.
```

And

```
$ g++ -Wall main.cpp -o main
$ ./main
8
```